# How does the following clojure code run?

Tags: clojure

I read the doc about `condp` from clojuredoc. And in the doc I found the following code:

`(condp some [1 2 3 4]
         #{0 6 7} :>> inc
         #{4 5 9} :>> dec
         #{1 2 3} :>> #(+ % 3))`

The result of the above code is 3. But I don't understand why.

If someone could help me figure it out ? Tell me how does the code run.

Thank you~

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure let's start with a simpler case:

```
user> (condp some [1 2 3 4] 
             #{5}  :>> inc 
             :the-default-value)

:the-default-value
```

Builds this test:

```
user> (some #{5} [1 2 3 4])
nil
```

Because the test returns something falsy (nil is falsy) it skips this clause and returns the default value at the end because there are no more clauses to check.

If we use a test that passes

```
user> (condp some [1 2 3 4] #{1}  :>> inc :the-default-value)
2
```

It builds the test:

```
user> (some #{1} [1 2 3 4])
1
```

Which results in something truthy (1) so the search stops and this clause is accepted. **The `:>>` tells condp to take the result of the test and pass it to the function that follows**, in this case `inc`. Resulting in `2`

So in the original example the first test is:

```
(some #{0 6 7} [1 2 3 4])
```

Which is `nil` so this case is not accepted and the search continues. The second test is:

```
user> (some #{4 5 9} [1 2 3 4])
4
```

Which results in the truthy value 4, so it calls the provided function `dec` on the value 4:

```
user> (dec 4) 
3
```

and the search stops.

Answer (score 5):

In this example, `condp` tries the predicate `some` on each test expression in turn, with `[1 2 3 4]` as the second argument.

- `(some #{0 6 7} [1 2 3 4])` fails, returning `nil`.
- `(some #{4 5 9} [1 2 3 4])` succeeds, returning `4`.

`condp` then returns the result of applying the function corresponding to the succeeding test expression, in this case `dec`, to the test value `4`.